# Horizontally fix element

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed

Using `position:fixed` fixes an element both vertically and horizontally, but I want my element only to remain horizontally fixed. That is, I want it to scroll vertically with the rest of the page.

Is there any CSS way of doing this? If not, would monitoring scroll offsets and then moving the element be the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
.fixThisHorizontally {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Then,

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery('.fixThisHorizontally').css('left', document.body.scrollLeft);
});
```

Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
 position:absolute;overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;
```

did you try these

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible entirely with CSS. I would, indeed, use `position:absolute` and use JavaScript to change the `top` css value when the page is scrolled.

Comment: Did you mean "use `position:absolute` and use JavaScript to change the **`left`** css value when the page is scrolled"? (Or `position:fixed`+`top` ?)

Comment: I misunderstood the question it seems. I meant what I said. I thought 'scroll vertically with the page' meant the object moved up and down as the page does, thus appearing to stay in the same position. But yes, you'd need to change the `left` value for this.